# Wrong answer in My_SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My problem is "To count the number of movies for each year that had only female actors".

Table schema is as follows:

```
--------------------   -----------------------   ----------------------
|       Movie      |   |     Person           |  |       Cast         |
--------------------   ------------------------  ----------------------
| MID    |   year  |   |  PID     |   Gender  |  |    MID   |    PID  |
--------------------   ------------------------  ----------------------
```

I wrote the following MySQL Query:

```
SELECT m.year, COUNT(m.MID) AS Movies_Female FROM Movie m
        WHERE m.MID IN ( SELECT Q.MID FROM ( SELECT m_c.MID, COUNT(m_c.PID) AS No_Actors FROM M_Cast m_c GROUP BY m_c.MID) Q 
        WHERE Q.No_Actors = ( SELECT COUNT(m__c.PID) FROM M_Cast m__c JOIN PERSON p 
        ON TRIM(p.PID) = TRIM(m__c.PID)
        WHERE m__c.MID = Q.MID AND TRIM(p.Gender) = 'Female')) GROUP BY m.year
```

But and I am getting the output as :

```
    year    Movies_Female
0   1939        1
1   1999        1
2   2000        1
3   2009        1
4   2012        1
5   2018        1
```

But when I am manually checking the year 2009 and 2012 don't have any Movie where there are only female actors. Please resolve where my query is going wrong?

Comment: Please can you improve the formatting of your SQL query? It is very difficult to read at the moment.

Comment: are you sure you mean `count the number of films with only female actors` (that would pretty much exclude almost every film, apart from weird art flicks)

Comment: @MrHeelis Seems like a reasonable request to me; so what if it's a small number?

Comment: @Strawberry because it would be much more likely he has not explained that part of his question thoroughly, listen to what he says "in 2009 and 2012 I do not have any"... if it is what he says, to check if he is right all he has to do is a m2m, sort by count of both and count of female and physically look for all the times the total equals the females..

Comment: @Heelis I run a query for all the MID's which were returned where all the actors where Female and then manually checked those MID and found PID's and Gender of those 6 MID's. So i found that those two values where the year is 2009 and 2012 are incorrect. The Gender for those values i found manually is 'None'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `not exists` to filter out movies that have a least one non-female actor:

```
select m.year, count(*) as movies_female 
from movie m
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from cast c
    inner join person p on p.pid = c.pid
    where c.mid = m.mid and p.gender <> 'Female'
)
group by m.year
```

This assumes that each and every movie has at least one entry in `cast` (which seems like a reasonable hypothesis here).